# jQuery + substr all elements using proper class

Tags: jquery, class, substr

I have a problem - please see a part of my code:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">zxcvbnm</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">abc</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">poiuytrewq</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I want to get all the elements using "qwerty" class and substr them to 3 characters + "...".
So I want to get such results as below:

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">zxc...</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">abc</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="qwerty">poi...</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text` method:

```
$('.qwerty').text(function(i,v){
    return v.length > 3 ? v.slice(0, 3) + '...' : v
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NEJR4/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

```
$(".qwerty").each(function() {
    var s = $(this).text();
    if (s.length > 3) s = s.substr(0, 3) + "...";
    $(this).text(s);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    $('.qwerty').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text.length>3)
      text = text.substr(0,3)+"...";
    $(this).text(text);
    });
```

Comment: That puts the ellipsis on even when it is not needed.